# How to unmarshal json

Tags: json, go

I am using http.Get in go to a url which results in the following
{"name":"cassandra","tags":["2.2.6","latest"]} that means it behaves like map[string]string for the name field but in the tags it behaves like map[string][]string  so how can I unmarshal this in Go?
I tried using map[string][]string but it did not work

```
map_image_tags := make(map[string][]string)    
res2, err := http.Get(fmt.Sprintf("%s/v2/%s/tags/lists", sconf.RegistryConf.url, Images[i]))
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(500)
            log.Errorf("could not get tags: %s", err)
            return
        }
        log.Debugf("OK")
        js2, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res2.Body)
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(500)
            log.Errorf("could not read body: %s", err)
            return
        }
        log.Debugf("OK")
        err = json.Unmarshal(js2, map_image_tags)
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(500)
            log.Errorf("could not unmarshal json: %s", err)
            return
        }
```

I am getting this log error: could not unmarshal json: invalid character 'p' after top-level value

Comment: Don't spam tags! C is a completely different language!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure of json data is dynamic you can unmarshal `tags` into `map[string]interface{}`:

```
var encodedTags map[string]interface{}
result := json.Unmarshal([]byte(image_tags), &encodedTags)
```

Then you can use type assertion to unmarshal the content of `tags`:

```
var tags []interface{}
result = json.Unmarshal([]byte(encodedTags["tags"].(string)), &tags)
```

And here is a full working example on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pkMkCcG-Sb).

Answer (score 2):

To read a json value like `{"name":"cassandra", "tags":["2.2.6","latest"]`, you can use a struct defined as:

```
type mapImageTags struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Tags []string `json:"tags"` // tags is a slice (array) of strings
}
```

To unmarshal JSON data,

```
m := mapImageTags{}
err = json.Unmarshal(js2, &m)
```

A simple `map[string]string` wont help in this case.

Comment: If the structure of the json is static then you should always unmarshal into structs like this. If it's dynamic you have to unmarshal into map[string]interface{}, which forces you to do some type checking/assertion before you can actually access the data in the interfaces.

Comment: @abhink The name and tags are static but i still having the same error

Comment: @Said try logging the actual json string. See if there's anything wrong with that. (More specifically, look for a `p`)

Answer (score 1):

Try `map[string]interface{}`, note that this method forces any numbers to `float` and in general not recommended when your json is complex. [abhink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3129778/abhink)'s answer is the recommended way.